# Calling Vuex mutator within Axios interceptor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

I would like to trigger a mutation from within an interceptor. In this case, trigger the `logout` mutation whenever Axios encounters an http 403.

I imported Vuex mutations and mapped as I've done elsewhere but I have not been able to access it within the Axios interceptor error function. I've added my interceptor config in App.vue's created() method.

I've tried the syntax from these 2 questions without success, most likely due to my project using modules, and the Axios config being located in a `created()` method.

1. https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/eq5eej/question_how_to_access_vuex_store_modules_mode_in/ <- Axios config in a seperate file, *is this the best practice?*
2. [Can't access Vuex storage mutation inside Axios interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49632461/cant-access-vuex-storage-mutation-inside-axios-interceptor) <- Not using modules

**App.vue**

```
<script>
import { mapMutations } from "vuex";
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(["logout"])
  },
  created(){
    axios.interceptors.response.use(
      function (response) {
        return response;
      }, 
      function (error) {
        if (error.response.status === 403) {
          this.logout()
            .then(() => {
              this.$router.push("/");
            })
        }
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

**EDIT**
Adding screenshot of results from the below answers
[image]

Comment: D'you see any error in the console? Also, you might wanna use arrow functions for the interceptor callbacks for `this` to refer to the Vue instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will either need to use an arrow function or bind the this context to your function in order to access `this` correctly

```
<script>
import { mapMutations } from "vuex";
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(["logout"])
  },
  created(){
    axios.interceptors.response.use(
      function (response) {
        return response;
      }, 
      (error) => {
        if (error.response.status === 403) {
          this.logout()
            .then(() => {
              this.$router.push("/");
            })
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
import { mapMutations } from "vuex";
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(["logout"])
  },
  created(){
    axios.interceptors.response.use(
      function (response) {
        return response;
      }, 
      function (error) {
        if (error.response.status === 403) {
          this.logout()
            .then(() => {
              this.$router.push("/");
            })
        }
      }.bind(this)
    );
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: For some reason, this is still undefined. I've added a shot in debug.

Answer (score 2):

You are close. The only thing that is stopping you is that you were declaring functions using the `function() {}` declaration, rather than the "fat-arrow" function declaration, which was creating a new scope (`this` was different). You should see the differences between the two changes below.

```js
// Your current script.
import { mapMutations } from "vuex";
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(["logout"])
  },
  created(){
    axios.interceptors.response.use(
      function (response) {
        return response;
      }, 
      function (error) {
        if (error.response.status === 403) {
          this.logout()
            .then(() => {
              this.$router.push("/");
            })
        }
    });
  }
}


// Updated
import { mapMutations } from "vuex";
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(["logout"])
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.interceptors.response.use(
      (response) => response, 
      (error) => {
        if (error.response.status === 403) {
          return this.logout()
            .then(() => this.$router.push("/"));
        }
        else {
          return Promise.reject(err);
        }
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: For some reason, this is still undefined. I've added a shot in debug.

Comment: @Half_Duplex => I made an edit, but the reason it still doesn't exist is because of the Lifecycle Hook that you have chosen. You need to change it from `created()` to `mounted()`.